# here.com API key is not authorized

Tags: python, api-key

I'm trying to use here.com's [routing api](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/calculate-route.html). Same as the example, I'm using the code below.

```
import requests

url = 'https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&origin=52.5308,13.3847&destination=52.5323,13.3789&return=summary&apiKey={api_key}'

response = requests.request("GET", url)

print(response.json())
```

I have a registered account and have replaced the `api_key` with the actual API key given in the account. Still, I keep getting the following error: `{'error': 'Unauthorized', 'error_description': 'apiKey invalid. apiKey not found.'}`

Anything wrong with the code? They don't have customer support for freemium users (sensible I guess).

Comment: are you wrapping the api key in the `{ }` when passing it?

Comment: I do, Without them the error is that the apiKey is expired.

Comment: So the braces are not meant to be there you just put the api key. If its saying expired then you need to see if you can create a new key or refresh it

Comment: That did it! Thanks.